# Problema ao criar o devise User + Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Estou tentando colocar uma entidade que já tinha no meu projeto como devise para fazer o login e etc, usei os seguintes comandos

add no Gemfile a linha `gem 'devise'`
no terminal executei:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
```

depois de fazer isso ele gerou um arquivo para alteração no banco:

```
#20160114174028_add_devise_to_users.rb
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

e alterou meu routes e meu model, sendo que no routes ele add a linha `devise_for :users`, porem antes estava com o meu controlador dentro de uma pasta api então ficou assim meu routes.br

```
#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    devise_for :users

    resources :schedules, except: [:new, :edit]
    # resources :users, except: [:new, :edit]
  end
end
```

e meu model ele adicionou uma linhas ficando assim:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :schedules
end
```

o problema é que quando fui dar o comando `rake db:migrate` deu a seguinte saida:

```
== 20160113192834 CreateSchedules: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:schedules)
   -> 0.0022s
== 20160113192834 CreateSchedules: migrated (0.0027s) =========================

rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUsers
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `load_migration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1048:in `use_transaction?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `rescue in block in migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `block in migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateUsers
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `load_migration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:770:in `migration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1048:in `use_transaction?'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1040:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@rails_4_2_jet2go/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Um erro parecido já tinha acontecido comigo e apenas corrigi dando um `rake db:drop`, mas dessa vez não deu certo.

Isso já aconteceu com mais alguem na hora de gerar o devise, e melhor alguem sabe como fazer dar certo e o porque acontece isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então descobri. Isso acontece quando o nome da classe de migração esta diferente do nome do arquivo.

Por exemplo o meu arquivo de criação estava: `20160114164439_create_users.rb` e a minha classe estava `class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration`, foi só corrigir o nome da classe para `class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration`.

Ai é só dar o comando: `rake db:migrate`